# WITH Hold Option in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am learning Oracle.

```
 CURSOR A  FOR TABLE1
 LOOP
     DELETE B TABLE RECORD BASED ON CURSOR A
 END LOOP
```

1. I am reading a Cursor from Table A,  and based on the result i am deleting 2 more table entries.  Please let me know in this case i need to provide FOR UPDATE OF while declaring Oracle or Its not needed.  In DB2 i know we need to give with hold option.
2. How to get the current user details in the query in oracle. In sql server if we give USER then the details will come.

Comment: A cursor based approach is almost always the wrong choice, a `delete from b where some_col in (select other_col from a)` will usually be **much** more efficient than a cursor based solution.

Answer (score 1):

This link may be useful while learning Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/portal.all_books

Open this link, click on `PL/` at the top of the page, then open `PL/SQL Language Reference`, 
and in chapter 13 `PL/SQL Language elements` find `DELETE Statement extension`:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/delete_statement.htm#LNPLS1187

Basically, to delete a record fetched from a cursor, a cursor must use `FOR UPDATE` clause, and a delete command must have `WHERE CUFFENT OF <cursor-variable>` clause.
An example:

```
  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT employee_id, job_id, salary
    FROM employees FOR UPDATE;
BEGIN
  OPEN c1;
  LOOP
    FETCH c1 INTO my_emp_id, my_job_id, my_sal;
    EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
    IF my_job_id = 'SA_REP' THEN
      DELETE employees
      WHERE CURRENT OF c1;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: If you want to use a cursor you may want to at least use an implicit cursor for loop - it will will be simpler and will automatically bulk collect the SELECT.

Comment: I don't think that it's strictly true that you have to use FOR UPDATE and WHERE CURRENT OF -- you could just issue a delete based on ROWID, but of course the record might already be locked.